# jquery save $(this), and re-run(re-write) it, it does not works well.

Tags: javascript, jquery

**CODE:**

```
<a href="#"><span class="clickable" id="span_resend">Resend</span></a>

<script>
$('#span_resend').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var save_this = $(this);
            var middle_this = $('<span class="loader">now_loading</span>');
            $(this).replaceWith(middle_this)
            $.ajax({
                url:'/ajax/',
                type:'post',
                dataType:'json',
                cache:false,
                data:{
                    com: 'some',
                },
                success:function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    if (data.res === 'success'){
                        middle_this.replaceWith(save_this)
                    }
                }
            });
        })
</script>
```

It works well when I click resend first.

However cause of script tag, there will be term of `now_loading` and after loaded, then clicking `#span_resend` does not works well.

I think it's from that I did not bind click function well on `#span_resend`.

But I don't know how to do it.

How can I do this?

**More explanation:** This code is to get ajax response from server, and that ajax response takes some time, maybe 10~15 seconds. So I want to change my resend button to show that ajax is being called, at the same time user cannot click during the waiting of ajax response from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**

Here's what's happening in your code that isn't obvious right away. On first click, you create a jQuery object containing the clicked span, you save this to a variable and after your post completes, you then replace the temporary span with the value of the variable.

Seems like everything should be just fine, but what you've actually done is dynamically added a control to your HTML and while the html of the control is identical to the original span, it is *not* the same control.

**Why does this matter?**

Events. It's all about events. When you copy a control, you aren't copying those event listeners associated with it too. So when that event fires again, it looks for the original control and doesn't find it.

You can read in depth about events and event listeners [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

So great, what do you do about all this?

**The Solution:**

The answer here is to bind those events to a control that is higher than the one you're replacing and won't be replaced itself. So maybe your body tag, or even the document tag. Here's what that would look like in your code:

```
// Instead of this:
$('#span_resend').click(function (e) {
    // Some code.
});

// Do this:
$(document).on('click', '#span_resend', function (e) {
    // Some code.
});
```

This ensures that those event listeners aren't removed when you replace the control.

Here's a mock up of your code using this method:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#span_resend', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var save_this = $(this);
            var middle_this = $('<span class="loader">now_loading</span>');
            $(this).replaceWith(middle_this)
            $.ajax({
                url:'https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=3',
                type:'post',
                dataType:'json',
                cache:false,
                data:{
                    com: 'some',
                    res: 'success'
                },
                success:function (data) {
                    if (data.res === 'success'){
                        middle_this.replaceWith(save_this);
                    }
                }
            });
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><span class="clickable" id="span_resend">Resend</span></a>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not replacing the button with a now loading but to hide it and show a separate loading indicator, then revert back once it's done

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#saveBtn").click(saveData);
});

function saveData() {
  $('#saveBtn').hide();
  $('#nowLoadingInd').show();
  //AJAX here instead of timeout (just for demo purpose)
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#saveBtn').show();
    $('#nowLoadingInd').hide();
  }, 10000);
}
```

```css
#saveBtn {
  display:inline-block;
  background:green;
  color:white;
  border-radius:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:3px 5px
}
#nowLoadingInd {
  color:gray
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="saveBtn">Save!</div>
    <div id="nowLoadingInd" style="display:none">Now Loading...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can pass an element to your ajax options and reference it in the then callback with the this object:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"yourUrl",
    data:{your:"data"},
    extraProperty:$('#yourElem')
}).then(function() {
    this.extraProperty.show()
});
```